# SMTP configuration on Plesk Server (Centos)

Tags: smtp, php-7, plesk

I'm trying to make code to send a simple mail via SMTP, I read that I must use the class `phpmailer` and also install pear engine on the server root, I downloaded some different files to authenticate the SMTP but always requires more files that I don't have or cant be charged. Actually, the PHP errors display this:

> Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/opt/plesk/php/7.1/share/pear/PEAR.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/necotec.es/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/necotec.es/httpdocs/prueba_smtp/Mail.php on line 48
>
> Warning: require_once(/opt/plesk/php/7.1/share/pear/PEAR.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/necotec.es/httpdocs/prueba_smtp/Mail.php on line 48
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PEAR.php' (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.1/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/necotec.es/httpdocs/prueba_smtp/Mail.php on line 48

I dont know if cant be found or is a permision problem the files by default takes 644 permisions in this server. Any clue would be helpfull thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> open_basedir restriction in effect

error means that some files or scripts are located out of allowed directory. 
In your case this file is `/opt/plesk/php/7.1/share/pear/PEAR.php`.

In Plesk you can disable open_basedir(not secure): **Domains > example.com > PHP Settings** and set open_basedir to `none`.

Another way(more secure) is to set open_basedir as `{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}:/opt/plesk/php/7.1`

I was able to configure PHPMailer on my test server(Plesk 17.5-17.8) using steps:

1. Logged in to the server using SSH
2. Went to domain Document root directory: `# cd /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/`
3. Run the command taken from [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer): `# composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`
4. As a result "vendor" folder appeared in "httpdocs" folder.
5. Created a testmail.php file based on [0-send-email-plesk.php](https://gist.github.com/emmgfx/7762b85e924c24f7575fe36c315ff0e7):

   ```
   <?php

   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

   //Load Composer's autoloader
   require 'vendor/autoload.php';
   $mail = new PHPMailer;
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; # 0 off, 1 client, 2 client y server
   $mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
   $mail->Host = 'localhost';
   $mail->Port = 25;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; # SSL is deprecated
   $mail->SMTPOptions = array (
       'ssl' => array(
           'verify_peer'  => true,
           'verify_depth' => 3,
           'allow_self_signed' => true,
           'peer_name' => 'Plesk',
       )
   );
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->Username = 'sender@example.com';
   $mail->Password = 'password';
   $mail->setFrom('sender@example.com', 'Name Surname');
   $mail->addAddress('recipient@domain.tld', 'Name Surname');
   $mail->Subject = 'Email subject';
   $mail->msgHTML('Email content with <strong>html</strong>');
   if (!$mail->send()) {
       echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   } else {
       echo "Message sent!";
   }
   ?>
   ```

   It assumes that local mail server is used and Default Plesk self signed certificate is used by mail server: **Plesk > Tools & Settings > SSL/TLS Certificates > Certificate for securing mail**